# Construct a C array from CSV data

Tags: c, arrays, csv, count

So, I am trying to build a c program to be able to read star catalogues and store them in arrays for further analysis.

Star catalogues usually come in .csv format and have a LOT of data on them, also **some slots are empty** and **not all of them have int, double or float type data**.

I want this program to be able to read "any" star catalogue (or by that matter any .csv file).

My first aproaches to construct such program met the issue that arrays must have their sizes declared, I decided to bypass this by creating a line and column counter functions, to be implemented by the main function.

```
int* getfield(char* line){
    FILE *fp = fopen("./hipparcos.csv", "r");
    int ch;
    int lines=0;
    do{
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if( ch== '\n'){
            lines++;    
        }    
    }while( ch != EOF );    

    printf("number of lines in the file %d\n",lines);
    return lines;
}
```

which does work well when implemented in the main function like this `getfield("\n");` so I get to see how many lines it is reading in the terminal (therefore know its counting them somehow).

What I need is to know ***how to store that quantity as a variable*** to later declare the array size and store lines in every position, and maybe after that do a line split (and separate each line into every column).

Any insights into how to proceed or a more efficient approach is appreciated.

Comment: You will waste a lot of time, there is a libcsv somewhere google it.

Comment: Why `char* line` parameter is needed in your function?

Comment: May I recommend [The Practice of Programming](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/) by Kernighan & Pike.  It's an excellent read, and one of their examples is of a mini-library for reading CSV files. It covers some of the many gotchas associated with CSV format. You can find _an_ official definition of CSV at the IETF ([RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)), but be aware that Microsoft has a different (de facto?) definition. There are variants on the theme, of greater or less precision — it isn't uncommon to find tab-delimited or semicolon-delimited formats called CSV. Anarchy rules!

Comment: Note that it is often a bad idea to read a file twice, once just to find how many lines there are and then to store the data.  You can use either memory mapping of the whole file into memory, or you can use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` and friends, growing your array carefully as needed. Apart from the time taken to read the file twice, there are some file types that can't be reread (sockets, pipes, terminals, to name but a few). Granted, here you have a disk file, but your code can be independent of that. It's also best to pass the filename into a function; it's easier to change.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler when would I be reading the file twice?

Comment: Once to count the number of lines in it, and once to read the data in it...or is the reading function incomplete and actually going to end up storing the lines. Incidentally, the function in the question leaks a file stream; you need to `fclose(fp)` before returning.

Comment: I will store the lines but I must count them first to be able to set up an array big enough to hold them right? as in int a[5][5]={0} creates a 2D array of 5 rows and 5 columns

Comment: No (you don't need to know how many lines will be read in advance); that was the point of my comment. You do need to know how to allocate and grow a dynamic array, though.  Are you on a machine with the POSIX (C) function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)?  If so, that will make your life easier; it will allocate the memory for each line if you use it correctly.

Comment: Then I believe I asked the wrong question.

Comment: "I believe I asked the wrong question" — that happens; it isn't even very unusual.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70983/discussion-between-carlos-sanchez-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You returns just int value, so change header of function to

```
int getfield(char* line){
```

this should not be a pointer.

Also consider possibility of not presence of `'\n'` at the end of the last line of the file (in this case you will have result 1 less than the number of rows).

**EDIT:**

If you just want to count number of lines as number of `'\n'` characters changed function is as follows:

```cpp
int getCharCount(char chr){
    FILE *fp = fopen("./hipparcos.csv", "r");
    int ch;
    int lines = 0;
    do{
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if( ch == chr){
            lines++;   
        }    
    }while( ch != EOF );
    fclose(fp); 
    return lines;
}
```

you can call this from `main()` e.g.:

```cpp
    printf("number of lines in the file %d\n", getCharCount('\n')); // maybe +1 needed :-)
```

but I understand that it is a draft of your program, so consider as an option sending file name as a parameter to your function. This make your solution more flexible.

Comment: Thank you, this worked to get the number of lines into my main. The char* line i need to run the function and search for the specific char "\n" so that the function seeks lines.

Comment: identifier `line` is not used inside function :-)  now, it is not used yet

Comment: @Carlos Sanchez : I have updated my post adding other example, but of course this is not the solution for reading data from CSV. When you made decision concerning storing the data in the program, ask again about reading from file to your data structure (if you have a questions).

Comment: I just Assumed for some reason that the function had to have some declared variable in it. but by changing the     'ch == chr'  for  'ch=='\n' we are all set to call it void.